# Absolute value of roots of bad Euler factors.

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, l-functions

Suppose $V$ is a smooth projective variety over number field $\mathbb{Q}$. For every prime integer $p$ and positive integer $j$, let
\begin{equation}
Z_p(H^j(V), T):=\det(1-{\rm Frob}_p\cdot T|H^j_{et}(X, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})^{I_p})
\end{equation}
where $I_p$ is the corresponding inertia group. Then according to the famous Weil-conjecture, we know that when $p$ is a "good" prime, i.e. when $H^j_{et}(X, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})^{I_p}=H^j_{et}(X, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$, then all roots of $Z_p(H^j(V), T)$ has absolute value $p^{j/2}$.

My question is: How about when $p$ is "bad", i.e.  when $H^j_{et}(X, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})^{I_p}\neq H^j_{et}(X, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$, can we still say something about the absolute value of its roots?

Any hint or reference is appreaciated.

Comment: @reuns For elliptic curves $E$, $Z_p(H^1(E), T)=1\pm T$ or $1$ and bad $p$. Hence it means the roots has absolute value bounded by $p^{1/2}$. But I don't know if this is also true for higher dimensional varieties.

Comment: For a curve with bad reduction $C= \cup Spec(R_j/(p))$, is it enough to look at the $R_j/(p)/I$ for each minimal prime ideal to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius acting on the Picard group ?

Comment: @reuns I am not sure I get your point. Would you mind explaining a little bit about it?